# J-- Compiler Source Code Attachment

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I'm reading a book right now, Its called: "Introduction to Compiler Construction in a Java World". So from their website you can download the source code of the compiler that one must use. -> http://www.cs.umb.edu/j--/download.html My problem is that I would like to follow the process of the compiler through debugging. But it doesnt work, because you have to attach the source code, which I tried, but it doesnt seem to work. I attached class files, java files, the jar, nothing works. So does someone know how to fix that problem?

Edit1: In eclipse

Edit2: Maybe this helps to understand my Problem better-> http://postimg.org/image/9pd2gyle7/
I wanna see what happens in the compiler process. But I cant see the main class, even though I have the main source code :S

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: We don't like links to external sites here, because when the link dies the question/answer is useless. And what's J--- in the question title for?

Comment: Well, thats cool. But if someone wants to help me, he can emulate my problem and solve it easier.   PS: J-- is the name of the compiler I try to see in my debugger

Comment: "We" don't like links?  *Some* people don't like links.  I think links are fine; they prevent the need from copying the entire internet into SO inch by inch.  Worse, if you copy data into SO, it becomes stale, but the maintainer of the linked-to location may actually keep something up to date.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, you did attach sources, make sure to define a [source attachment](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-source-attachment.htm&cp=1_4_3_4) in a way that Eclipse understands. If that's what you tried, more information would be necessary to tell why it didn't work.